# jquery and z-index delay not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move a div from behind one div to on top of another but in a seamless way as if you would swap a card from the bottom of the deck to the top.

What I'm trying to accomplish would have the div with a -9 z-index from css move to the right, apply a new z-index, then slide it back to the left on top of the other div.

The problem I'm running into, regardless of delay, the z-index gets applied instantly so the effect isn't there.

```
    $('#reportright').animate({left: '900px'}, 350);
    $('#reportright').delay(200).css('z-index', 3000);
    $('#reportright').animate({left: '500px'}, 350);
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it in queue:

```
 $('#reportright').delay(200).queue(function (next) {
     $(this).css('z-index', 3000);
     next();
 });
```